# Forcing browser to reload the history URLs when going back

Tags: html, browser-history

Is there a method of forcing browser to refresh what URLs to load while going back in the browser history?

In a nutshell: There is a (slow) item search. On top of this item search there are additional AJAX filters that replace the item results of this search (it's another item search with extra parameters in the URL). There is a multiple of those filters that can be applied to a search. Eventually the user clicks on an item they're interested in or adds it to the cart or whatever other action.

By default, if they click back in the browser, it will load the initial search without the additional AJAX filters applied. That's understandable.

To have a proper back behaviour, I've used the [jQuery.history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) plugin. I can see very nicely the URLs in the address bar change properly, but it never "reloads" that URL, instead, it tries to force loading previous page and AJAXing the rest. At least that's my understanding.

So even though the address bar will show a correct search link, on which if I were to press enter the correct results would load, but the browser never refreshes that link.

Now, I'm sure I could call the AJAX filters again if I had to, but I'm hoping there is a way of forcing a refresh when the person clicks back in their browser.

I'm not even sure if what I'm asking for is possible.